# mocking a parametrized map in mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito

I have a map that looks like this `Map<String, Class<? extends TypeA>> differentTypesOfA;` 
I have different subclasses of TypeA

`Class TypeB implements TypeA {..}` 
`Class TypeC implements TypeA {..}`
and so on

I put them into the map somewhere `differentTypesOfA.put("TypeB",TypeB.class)`

Now I am trying to mock this map with

`@Mock Map<String, Class<? extends TypeA>> differentTypesOfAMock;` and then 
`.. setup() {`
`when(differentTypesOfAMock.get(anyString()).thenReturn(TypeB.class);`
`}`

This of course doesn't work but I can't figure out a nice way of mocking this map either. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you even need to mock it? Maybe you can just use a `HashMap`.

Comment: Don't mock it.  A map is a value object - I can't imagine any case where you'd want to stub its logic.  Just use a real map.

Comment: yeah i could use a real map, no problem. was just curious if it could be done.

Comment: @DavidWallace You should make that an answer so the OP can accept it (and I can upvote it).

Comment: Yeah, @user949110, it can probably be done.  There's no real point.

Comment: @DavidWallace ok, suppose I have a class which has this map as a field. and suppose there is no getter for the map or the getter doesn't serve a purpose because the class has some logic based on what the map has. And I need to mock that class in a test. in such a case you would need to mock the map as well, wouldn't you?

Comment: I don't see why.  If you mock the class, then surely there won't be a map any more?

Comment: the reason for mocking this class was to verify 2 method calls which were conditioned on what the map has. but you are right no point mocking a map. when you need something like that, you know there's something wrong with your design. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you only want verification of the Map.get() method, then you can use a real Map, and you can create a spy of it. Then you can pass the spy instead of the original object to the tested code, and then you can examine all calls to the map. (see http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13). You do not have to stub anything on the spy. A good example is here (in the question): [Is it a right case for Mockito spy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3692469/337621)